# What is the limit (if any) of datastores for ESXi?

Tags: storage, vmware-esxi, datastore

Is there a limit to the number and type of datastores that can be attached to an ESXi instance?

Specifically, is there a limit to the number of NFS mounts that can be added as data stores vs the number of SAN devices vs NAS appliances vs local storage, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Configuration Maximums](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40/vsp_40_config_max.pdf). Looks like 256 VMFS volumes per host max. And then:

- NFS-attached, limit of 64
- FC attached, limit of 256
- iSCSI attached, limit of 256

Comment: I *knew* it was an RTFM question... just didn't know which manual to look in :) thanks!

Comment: The linked document was the first result when I searched google for "vmware datastore limits".

Comment: your google-fu defeats mine today

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Have fun with your 256 VMFS volumes. :)